# Is there a way to calculate a figure and show the result in HTML5 without using forms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not a huge fan of Javascript so prefer to do as much as possible with HTML/CSS, probably to my disadvantage.

So my question is could I for example display one number 1.00 and then do a calculation on it eg (times it by 85) and show the output in HTML5? (Without using forms?).

I have seen examples that use inputs, but I don't really need user input, I just want it to do a calculation on load.

If you see one of my pages below, you will see that there are a list of prices and I want to convert them all to a different currency (I don't need  to get the currency rate (I can add that manually, just want it to do the basic calculation eg : 100 rupees = 0.95 pounds Calulation (100*0.95) Returns £0.95p

For example :

[Cost Of living in India example](http://www.beingchildren.org/Cost-of-Living-in-Goa-India.htm)

So I just want to input the current exchange rate in one place and it will calulate the £ rates for each entry in the list.

If this can't be done in HTML5, can someone suggest the bare minimum javascript to do the same?

Comment: Thanks Wilmoore and Vanga, for simplicity, I would go with Vanga's solution, are there any reasons why I shouldn't?  How would the processing/loading times differ between the two methods?

Comment: Well I have added the code, although I couldn't get the 2nd version to update so I have gone with the document write version.

Comment: http://www.beingchildren.org/Cost-of-Living-in-Goa-India.htm

Can someone suggest if this is good/bad implementation?

Comment: May be I will consider using some Templating Engine like : http://handlebarsjs.com/, http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/, http://mustache.github.io/ etc. It will take the pain of adding many static HTML elements. Instead we can show a template and feed data to it - It will create complete HTML Tags. Later we may feed data from the server instead of static data in the page. But it will need some JavaScript skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following simple JavaScript.

Create a new `<script>` tag in the head section as follows with some variable name.

```
<script>
    var exchange_rate = .95;
</script>
```

Where ever you want to do calculations use as following

```
<p>
    Cost of Cooking : 
    <script>
        document.write(exchange_rate * 100);
    </script>
</p>
```

So, if you change the `exchange_rate` in the head section's `<script>` tag, it will show proper values wherever you used it.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span id="costofliving">1.00</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var cost = document.getElementById('costofliving');

function calculate() {
    cost.innerText = Number(cost.innerText) * 85;
}

// will be set in 2 seconds
setTimeout(calculate, 2000);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SV7Hj/